# Differential of a shifted function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

If I'm given the differential equation:

$$\frac{d(12-24f(t))}{dt} = 5$$

How do I rearrange this so that it looks like a normal first order linear differential equation?

e.g, so it looks something like this:

$$a + B\frac{df(t)}{dt} = c$$

**My attempt so far:**

I can take the $-24$ outside of the differential

$$-24\frac{d(f(t)-0.5)}{dt} = 5$$

But then I do not know what to do with this $-0.5$ which shifts the function downwards. I would guess that you can just ignore it, as the rate of change of a function which has been shifted downwards is the same as the rate of change of the same function when it is unshifted. So I would guess the answer is:

$$24\frac{df(t)}{dt} = 5$$

But I'm unsure. I've never been taught this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is correct, as adding a constant $C$ to a function does not change its derivative. This is because (1) derivatives are linear operators and (2) the derivative of a constant is 0. Thus,

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(f(t) + C) = \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{dC}{dt} = \frac{df}{dt} + 0 = \frac{df}{dt} .
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have been taught this in your first course in differential calculus. recall that
$$\frac{d}{dt}(g(t)+h(t))=\frac{dg}{dt}(t)+\frac{dh}{dt}(t)$$
In particular
$$\frac{d(12-24f(t))}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}12+\frac{d}{dt}(-24f(t))=0-24\frac{df}{dt}(t)=-24\frac{df}{dt}(t)$$
What does the D.E. simplify to now?